# VS 2019 Show Potential Fixes (Fully Qualify vs Using)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

It only offers to put the full namespace before the class. I want it to put this outside the current class' namespace, so I do not have to use the full namespace name everytime I want to use [TestClass].

I know this setting used to be available, and I assume I have turned it off by accident.

[image: Potential Fixes example]

As mentioned by Amy, I want it to add a 'using' statement at the top of the class instead.

```
using Microsoft.Vs.Test;
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `using BlahBlahNamespace;` at the top of your file?

Comment: @Amy exactly, but I want it done through the potential fixes dialog.

Comment: One time this happen to me. Just restarting Visual Studio solved the problem to me. VS2019

Comment: There's a right arrow to the side of the first line in the context menu that expands into an additional context menu.  It should be available inside that sub-menu.

Comment: @KevinKouketsu Winner, thats all it was

Comment: Always try turning it off and back on again :)

Comment: Is it worth posting an answer or should I just delete this.. @KevinKouketsu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's a problem with some modules of Visual Studio. I remember having this problem but a couple of moments before that I saw a crash on the toolbar of VS.

Just restarting the Visual Studio solved the problem for me.
Maybe you can report to VS Team.